# Inconsistency between two apparently identical SQL commands running through ASP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a large database system in SQL Server 2012 and a front end interface written in ASP. Users can query the database and I also have a dictionary to pick up typos and alternate spellings.

Historically users could have a single word search, or a multi word AND or OR search. I have just finished writing an exact multi-word search, and the search includes the multiple variations from the dictionary.

In the examples below I am searching therefore for "stroke unit" or "storke unit" in various fields. Note that the  working version is text that I cut and pasted from output from the non-working version, and is not normally present. Apologies for the length of the statements, I just have a lot of fields to search. The AND and OR searches have much longer statements but I have never had any problem with them.

I have absolutely no idea why one version works and the other doesn't, so would be grateful for any tips. (I also don't normally have error checking every line of a connection statement, I just was hoping something might appear)

My code is currently

```
     Err.Clear
     LineOut("Version 1: Not working")
     Session("Version1")="INSERT INTO dbo.Temp_RCT_Existing_Results "+Session("DORIS_RCT_SEL")+Session("DORIS_RCT_FROM2")+" ORDER BY Acronym, Year DESC, Authors, Title"
     LineOut("<BR>-<BR>["+Session("Version1")+"]")
     SET conn =Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     LineOut("Error Number on Create ="+CStr(Err.Number))
     conn.Open adserverlocn
     LineOut("Error Number on Open="+CStr(Err.Number))
     conn.Execute Session("Version1")
     LineOut("Error Number on Execute="+CStr(Err.Number))
     conn.Close
     SET conn=Nothing

     LineOut("<BR>-<BR>Version 2: Working")
     Session("Version2")="SELECT DISTINCT REF.REF_ID AS RefID, REF.REF_LTITLE AS Title, REF.REF_AUTHRS AS Authors, REF.REF_YEAR AS Year, STUDY.ST_ACRONYM AS Acronym, REF.REF_CITATION AS Citation,REF.REF_URL,REF.REF_PUBID, STUDY.ST_INTDTLS AS StudyDets, STUDY.ST_ISRCTN ,STUDY.ST_NCT, STUDY.ST_Registers,STUDY.ST_UKCRN,STUDY.ST_NAME,STUDY.ST_SYSREV,STUDY.ST_STATUS,REF.REF_DORIS_ORDER, 'Bob2' AS BelongsTo,ST_DOI, '2016-11-08' AS SearchDate, STUDY.ST_SIZE, REF_ORTITL AS OTitle FROM INTERV INNER JOIN ST_INT ON INTERV.INT_ID = ST_INT.[INT] INNER JOIN STUDY ON ST_INT.ST = STUDY.STUDY_ID INNER JOIN REF_ST ON STUDY.STUDY_ID = REF_ST.ST INNER JOIN REF ON REF_ST.REF = REF.REF_ID WHERE STUDY.ST_CONFID='OPEN' AND REF.REF_PUBSTA='PUBLISHED' AND (((REF.REF_LTITLE LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR STUDY.ST_INTDTLS LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_METHOD LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE1 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE2 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE3 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE4 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_DISEASE LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CONDITION LIKE '%stroke UNIT %')) OR ((REF.REF_LTITLE LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR STUDY.ST_INTDTLS LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_METHOD LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE1 LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE2 LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE3 LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CODE4 LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_DISEASE LIKE '%storke UNIT %' OR INTERV.INT_CONDITION LIKE '%storke UNIT %'))) AND (Study.st_sysrev='-') AND (study.st_status='COMPLETED')"
     Session("Version2")="INSERT INTO dbo.Temp_RCT_Existing_Results "+Session("Version2")+" ORDER BY Acronym, Year DESC, Authors, Title"
     LineOut("<BR>-<BR>["+Session("Version2")+"]")
     SET conn =Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     conn.Open adserverlocn
     conn.Execute Session("Version2")
     conn.Close
     SET conn=Nothing
```

The output for this is

---

Version 1: Not working

```
INSERT INTO DBO.temp_rct_existing_results
SELECT DISTINCT ref.ref_id       AS RefID,
                ref.ref_ltitle   AS Title,
                ref.ref_authrs   AS Authors,
                ref.ref_year     AS Year,
                study.st_acronym AS Acronym,
                ref.ref_citation AS Citation,
                ref.ref_url,
                ref.ref_pubid,
                study.st_intdtls AS StudyDets,
                study.st_isrctn,
                study.st_nct,
                study.st_registers,
                study.st_ukcrn,
                study.st_name,
                study.st_sysrev,
                study.st_status,
                ref.ref_doris_order,
                'Bob'            AS BelongsTo,
                st_doi,
                '2016-11-08'     AS SearchDate,
                study.st_size,
                ref_ortitl       AS OTitle
FROM   interv
       INNER JOIN st_int
               ON interv.int_id = st_int.[int]
       INNER JOIN study
               ON st_int.st = study.study_id
       INNER JOIN ref_st
               ON study.study_id = ref_st.st
       INNER JOIN ref
               ON ref_st.ref = ref.ref_id
WHERE  study.st_confid = 'OPEN'
       AND ref.ref_pubsta = 'PUBLISHED'
       AND ( (( ref.ref_ltitle LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR study.st_intdtls LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_method LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code1 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code2 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code3 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code4 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_disease LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_condition LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' ))
              OR (( ref.ref_ltitle LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR study.st_intdtls LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_method LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code1 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code2 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code3 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code4 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_disease LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_condition LIKE '%storke UNIT %' )) )
       AND ( study.st_sysrev = '-' )
       AND ( study.st_status = 'COMPLETED' )
ORDER  BY acronym,
          year DESC,
          authors,
          title
```

Error Number on Create =0

Error Number on Open=0

Error Number on Execute=0

---

Version 2: Working

```
INSERT INTO DBO.temp_rct_existing_results
SELECT DISTINCT ref.ref_id       AS RefID,
                ref.ref_ltitle   AS Title,
                ref.ref_authrs   AS Authors,
                ref.ref_year     AS Year,
                study.st_acronym AS Acronym,
                ref.ref_citation AS Citation,
                ref.ref_url,
                ref.ref_pubid,
                study.st_intdtls AS StudyDets,
                study.st_isrctn,
                study.st_nct,
                study.st_registers,
                study.st_ukcrn,
                study.st_name,
                study.st_sysrev,
                study.st_status,
                ref.ref_doris_order,
                'Bob2'           AS BelongsTo,
                st_doi,
                '2016-11-08'     AS SearchDate,
                study.st_size,
                ref_ortitl       AS OTitle
FROM   interv
       INNER JOIN st_int
               ON interv.int_id = st_int.[int]
       INNER JOIN study
               ON st_int.st = study.study_id
       INNER JOIN ref_st
               ON study.study_id = ref_st.st
       INNER JOIN ref
               ON ref_st.ref = ref.ref_id
WHERE  study.st_confid = 'OPEN'
       AND ref.ref_pubsta = 'PUBLISHED'
       AND ( (( ref.ref_ltitle LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR study.st_intdtls LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_method LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code1 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code2 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code3 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_code4 LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_disease LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'
                 OR interv.int_condition LIKE '%stroke UNIT %' ))
              OR (( ref.ref_ltitle LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR study.st_intdtls LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_method LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code1 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code2 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code3 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_code4 LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_disease LIKE '%storke UNIT %'
                     OR interv.int_condition LIKE '%storke UNIT %' )) )
       AND ( study.st_sysrev = '-' )
       AND ( study.st_status = 'COMPLETED' )
ORDER  BY acronym,
          year DESC,
          authors,
          title
```

If I cut and and post the non-working version into the SQL Server Management Studio, it works perfectly. I have also swapped the order of the working and non-working versions to see if it makes any difference.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I should have added: "not working"=doesn't write to the table

Comment: when you say you have switched the sequence of the insert statements, is it always the second that fails? Please explain. Also I checked the SQL and they are identical apart from 'bob' v's 'bob2' in a column alias but that should not be an issue since this is a position delimited insert.  Lastly, there can be a significant difference between running in SQL management studio versus an ADODB connection.

Comment: Just to add that the errors in the ADODB connection may not be appearing in the ASP error object. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_error.asp for details of how to look inside the ADODB error collection. Poss try that ?

Comment: does LIKE work differently when you pass it through the ADODB connection?  what happens if you try a much simpler query searching for 'LIKE '%stroke UNIT %'' I seem to recall ODBC connections changing stuff like this sometimes - bit of a shot in the dark

Comment: what I'd do is start with a simple SQL statement and build it back up towards the original in stages, to find out where it breaks

Comment: Thanks wombat will look at the link. Re swapping - I put in the complete string as a command just to see if it worked, and I tried running it before and after the non-working version just to see if there was a timing issue, but the complete string works in either case.

Comment: Andrew, I can run much bigger statements which work (I just tried to post one but the comment was rejected as too big!) which is why I don't think the length is the problem.

Comment: Is there any way of posting longer comments here? :-(

Comment: @Ally string concatenation just begs for SQL Injection. It's also responsible to query errors due to unexpected conversions and strings. You simply can't be certain what was actually executed. It's also very difficult to fix problems when you can't work with the SQL statement itself. Create a stored procedure (that doesn't use concatenations itself) that performs the insertion. It's far easier to debug, safer and faster

Comment: @Ally the JOINS of your select statement, perhaps even the criteria,  could be replaced by a VIEW. On the other hand, it looks like you are trying to perform a full-text search for specific terms? Why don't you use a full text index?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis - I am a bit confused how I could create the stored procedures without concatenations as I don't know what people are going to be searching for? Also how would you advise setting up an index as I don't know what people are going to ask for and they can type in anything. Sorry if this sounds dumb...